# Get a different file size when the file is too big using FindFirstFile() function

Tags: c++, winapi

I used the below code which someone had posted on stackoverflow to check size of a big file(12gb). However it shows me different size(267 mb) when i check through this function. Can someone explain me whats the issue? for file size of 2gb , 3 gb the code shows the size correctly.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
   HANDLE hFind;
   LPCTSTR  lpFileName = L"C:\\Foo\\Bar.ext";

   hFind = FindFirstFile(lpFileName , &FindFileData);
   if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
   {
      printf ("File not found (%d)\n", GetLastError());
      return -1;
   } 
   else 
   {
      ULONGLONG FileSize = FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh;
      FileSize <<= sizeof( FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh ) * 8; 
      FileSize |= FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
      _tprintf (TEXT("file size is %u\n"), FileSize);
      FindClose(hFind);
   }
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: You are using the wrong printf() format specifier.  Use %llu

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, but unfortunately Microsoft decided to use their own format.  Unless this has been fixed recently, you must instead use `%I64u`.

Comment: It wasn't recent, %llu has been supported for the past 8 years already.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/56e442dc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I will when it costs the same as gcc =)

Comment: Thank you Hans. %llu works great too......

Comment: @paddy: It is the same price. You can [download the SDK for free](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line of your program does *not* print a 64-bit number:

```
_tprintf (TEXT("file size is %u\n"), FileSize);
```

In windows you need to use the format specifier `%I64u` to format a 64-bit (unsigned) integer.